# Convert multiple rows to single column in Ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have multiple rows which i want to convert it into single column:
For exa : Table1

```
ID      Field1         Field2        Field3
1         A              B            C
2         D              A           null
3         B             null         null
```

Result should be like below :

```
Field1
  A
  B
  C
  D
  A
  B
```

Please suggest how can we convert it into Ms access query or VBScript or any other way we can get the result in Ms access.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened to the ID values? A single column in the resultant table would be pretty meaningless. And why are the values A and B repeated?

Comment: @andy g  Let me do it more meaningful , we don't have id field,  only 3 fields are there and the values come repetitive that's fix. now we want to get the result which is mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` query combines results of other queries.

```
Select field1
From table1
Where field1 Is Not Null

UNION

Select field2 as field1
From table1
Where field2 Is Not Null

UNION

Select field3 as field1
From table1
Where field3 Is Not Null
```

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft.com : [**Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e)
- Wikipedia : [**Set Operations (SQL): UNION Operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator)

Comment: thanks for help , it works proper as u suggested , thanks a lot.